# How to get `DOM Element` in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, dom

I have a component that has a `<p>` element. It's `(click)` event will change it into a `<textarea>`. So, the user can edit the data. My question is:

- How can I make the focus on the `textarea`?
- How can I get the element, so I can apply the `.focus()` on it?
- Can I avoid using `document.getElemenntById()`?

I have tried to use the "ElementRef" and the "@ViewChild()" however it seems that I'm missing something:

**app.component.ts**

```js
@ViewChild('tasknoteId') taskNoteRef:ElementRef;

noteEditMode: boolean = false;

get isShowNote (){
  return  !this.noteEditMode && this.todo.note  ? true : false;
}
taskNote: string;
toggleNoteEditMode () {
  this.noteEditMode = !this.noteEditMode; 
  this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(
    this.taskNoteRef.nativeElement,'focus'
  );
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<span class="the-insert">
  <form [hidden]="!noteEditMode && todo.note">
    <textarea #tasknoteId id="tasknote"
     name="tasknote"
     [(ngModel)]="todo.note"
     placeholder="{{ notePlaceholder }}"
     style="background-color:pink"
     (blur)="updateNote()" (click)="toggleNoteEditMode()"
     [autofocus]="noteEditMode"
     [innerHTML]="todo.note">
   </textarea>
 </form>
</span>
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522306/angular-2-focus-on-newly-added-input-element

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Use **[ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description)** with  **#[TemplateVariable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables)** as shown here,

```
<textarea  #someVar  id="tasknote"
                  name="tasknote"
                  [(ngModel)]="taskNote"
                  placeholder="{{ notePlaceholder }}"
                  style="background-color: pink"
                  (blur)="updateNote() ; noteEditMode = false " (click)="noteEditMode = false"> {{ todo.note }} 

</textarea>
```

In component,

**OLDEST Way**

```
import {ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild('someVar') el:ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit()
{
   this.el.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

---

**OLD Way**

```
import {ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild('someVar') el:ElementRef;
    
constructor(private rd: Renderer) {}
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.rd.invokeElementMethod(this.el.nativeElement,'focus');
}
```

---

**Updated on 22/03(March)/2017**

**NEW Way**

Please note from **Angular v4.0.0-rc.3 (2017-03-10)** few things have been changed.
Since Angular team will deprecate **`invokeElementMethod`**, above code no longer can be used.

> BREAKING CHANGES

> since 4.0 rc.1:

> rename RendererV2 to Renderer2
> rename RendererTypeV2 to RendererType2
> rename RendererFactoryV2 to RendererFactory2

```
import {ElementRef,Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild('someVar') el:ElementRef;

constructor(private rd: Renderer2) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.rd); 
      this.el.nativeElement.focus();      //<<<=====same as oldest way
}
```

**`console.log(this.rd)`** will give you following methods and you can see now **`invokeElementMethod`** is not there. *Attaching img as yet it is not documented.*

**NOTE:** You can use following methods of **`Rendere2`** with/without **ViewChild variable** to do so many things.

[image]

Comment: it works only for the first time, do you have any idea ?

Comment: Yes it will work only once. What do u want?

Comment: @CoffeeCode you can move the this.rd.invokeElementMethod(this.el.nativeElement,'focus'); into another function and call it any time you want to make it the focus again

Comment: In fact, the whole `Renderer` will go away, but there's a `Renderer2` available (with other methods)

Comment: Can I find a child element of a Renderer2, maybe through selector perhaps?

Comment: What if you have an arbitrary number of elements that are unknown before loading the page?

Comment: @brianthomps please give us your scenario in a different question.

Comment: Can this all be true? In vue, you put a `ref="myDomEl"` on the element, then `this.$refs.myDomEl.focus()` or `.click()` or `.getBoundingClientRect()` or whatever. Nothing to import, works x times, works inside or outside vue. You don't want to be doing this all the time, but you don't want it to be impossible either???

Comment: Why do we have import statement with only ElementRef and no `ViewChild` itself? Why ViewChild is merged to imports and not in the class? 
I never will understand this.

Comment: How do we grab an element by tag name? I cannot place a #someVar ref on the element since it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @Crystal you still can use #someVar as you have to grab that element in `ngAfterViewinit`. By that time, element will become visible and you can grab & manipulate it.

Comment: So I was attempting to place a tabindex=0 on a component that was being dynamically created by a library - the template doesn't exist so I could not add the template ref to it (#someVar)... I have to wait for the dom to finish rendering to then grab it via vanilla javascript. However, as I understand Angular discourages that... this article helped though -> https://blog.angularindepth.com/working-with-dom-in-angular-unexpected-consequences-and-optimization-techniques-682ac09f6866

Answer (score 99):

**Update (using renderer):**

> Note that the original Renderer service has now been deprecated in
>   favor of Renderer2

as on [Renderer2 official doc.](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)

Furthermore, as pointed out by @GünterZöchbauer:

> Actually using ElementRef is just fine. Also using
>   ElementRef.nativeElement with Renderer2 is fine. What is discouraged
>   is accessing properties of ElementRef.nativeElement.xxx directly.

---

You can achieve this by using `elementRef` as well as by `ViewChild`. however it's not recommendable to use `elementRef` due to:

- security issue
- tight coupling

as pointed out by [official ng2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html).

## 1. Using `elementRef` (Direct Access):

```
export class MyComponent {    
constructor (private _elementRef : ElementRef) {
 this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('textarea').focus();
 }
}
```

## 2. Using `ViewChild` (**better approach**):

```
<textarea  #tasknote name="tasknote" [(ngModel)]="taskNote" placeholder="{{ notePlaceholder }}" 
style="background-color: pink" (blur)="updateNote() ; noteEditMode = false " (click)="noteEditMode = false"> {{ todo.note }} </textarea> // <-- changes id to local var


export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('tasknote') input: ElementRef;

   ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.input.nativeElement.focus();

  }
}
```

## 3. Using `renderer`:

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
      @ViewChild('tasknote') input: ElementRef;
         constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){           
          }

       ngAfterViewInit() {
       //using selectRootElement instead of depreaced invokeElementMethod
       this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.input["nativeElement"]).focus();
      }

    }
```

Comment: When I do all of your approach I get Cannot read property nativeElement pf undefined

Comment: Where did you use `renderer`? Just injected that on constructor

Comment: Same error here, when i try to do this approach on an <img/> i get "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined.."
I'm using Angular 5 and i tried to import the Elevant Zoom script.

Comment: You must add reference name (string after the '#') :
<textarea  
**#tasknote** 
name="tasknote" [(ngModel)]="taskNote" placeholder="{{ notePlaceholder }}"...

Comment: @Ryan updated answer to include `renderer` way as well.
@M98

Comment: @Ryan I actually tested the code given in the question above. as it had single element so it selected `textarea` as root element. :P
Thanks for the info and the link.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I'd like to ask a follow-up: Why is it recommended to put the focus code in `ngAfterViewInit()` as opposed to `ngOnInit()`? When I run it in the latter, it runs fine. When I run it in the former, I have some weird UI glitches.

Comment: @Knight we want our view to be initialized before setting focus on any particular element, so focus code should be in `ngAfterViewInit()`. If you can reproduce the issue in stackblitz, I can have a look.

Comment: `constructor (private _elementRef : ElementRef)` with capital E for me, import from core.

Comment: In the first approach, I use querySelector and I got the first element of that tag. Could you please update with how to get all elements with that particular selector?

Comment: @PrasadW you can use `@ViewChildren('elemName')` (second approach) to get all the elements.

Answer (score 11):

**Angular 2.0.0 Final:**

I have found that using a `ViewChild` setter is most reliable way to set the initial form control focus:

```
@ViewChild("myInput")
set myInput(_input: ElementRef | undefined) {
    if (_input !== undefined) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(_input.nativeElement, "focus");
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

The setter is first called with an `undefined` value followed by a call with an initialized `ElementRef`.

Working example and full source here: http://plnkr.co/edit/u0sLLi?p=preview

*Using TypeScript 2.0.3 Final/RTM, Angular 2.0.0 Final/RTM, and Chrome 53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit).*

**UPDATE for Angular 4+**

`Renderer` has been deprecated in favor of `Renderer2`, but `Renderer2` [does not have](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13818) the `invokeElementMethod`. You will need to access the DOM directly to set the focus as in `input.nativeElement.focus()`.

I'm still finding that the *ViewChild setter* approach works best. When using `AfterViewInit` I sometimes get `read property 'nativeElement' of undefined` error.

```
@ViewChild("myInput")
set myInput(_input: ElementRef | undefined) {
    if (_input !== undefined) {
        setTimeout(() => { //This setTimeout call may not be necessary anymore.
            _input.nativeElement.focus();
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: The ugly hack of wrapping the focus with `setTimeout` did the magic in my code. Thank you for this.

Comment: it is not reliable way if your html element is located in index.html