# Lifecycle hooks - angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to check/uncheck checkboxes based on a list of values I obtain from backend. I'm trying to do it immediately once I have finished painting the page.

My application code for fetching data is encapsulated in `ngOnInit`, and I'm trying to modify in `ngAfterContentChecked`. But, it is failing and when I do a `document.getElementById()` from my component, it is returning a `null`.

P.S: I can't be using `model` because I'm dealing with key-value pairs. Hence, I'm manually fetching values. More on this here - [Angular 2 - Displaying checkboxes using key-value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40578049/angular-2-displaying-checkboxes-using-key-value-pairs)

Edit 1:

Component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'xxx',
    templateUrl: './myHtml.html',
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentChecked {

myList: Param[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.myList = //logic for fetching data
  console.log(this.myList); // This is getting printed
}

ngAfterContentChecked() {
  console.log(this.myList); // This is also getting printed
  for ( var i = 0; i < this.myList; i++ ) {
    document.getElementById(this.myList[i].paramName.concat(this.myList[i].paramValue).checked = true;
  }
}
}
```

Html:

```
<div *ngFor="let var of myList">
  <input type="checkbox" id="{{param.paramName}}{{param.paramValue}}" value="{{var.paramValue}}"><label>{{var.paramValue}}</label>
</div>
```

`document.getElementById` in the component returns `null`

Edit 2: 
Just realized that `this.myList` is not getting logged - I was setting the value  from elsewhere and thought it was getting intialized.

Comment: Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Change `ngAfterContentChecked` to `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Tried that. No luck with that either

Comment: Kindly refer the link your query is answered. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944725/how-to-get-dom-element-in-angular-2