# Get element by id - Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a code:

```
document.getElementById('loginInput').value = '123';
```

But while compiling the code I receive following error:

> Property value does not exist on type HTMLElement.

I have declared a var: `value: string;`.

How can I avoid this error?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems you do want a component by id, not an element by id. That's not supported though.

Comment: Provide som more code

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer So how can I catch this element? `<input type='text' id='loginInput'/>`?

Comment: if you are using angular 2 you can use its data binding feature [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax)

Comment: you are trying to set the value of text-filed or want to get value from text-filed ? what you are trying to achive ?

Comment: @PardeepJain I want to set the value of login and password inputs, so I don't need to write it by myself every time I log into the application.

Comment: @Natalia please see my answer may help you.

Comment: Don't do that, just follow the angular.io tutorial on bindings... There are plenty of examples there

Answer (score 37):

if you want to set value than you can do the same in some function on click or on some event fire.

also you can get value using `ViewChild` using local variable like this

```
<input type='text' id='loginInput' #abc/>
```

and get value like this

```
this.abc.nativeElement.value
```

<kbd>[here is working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/buE3UX4MpcP1vrgof639?p=preview)</kbd>

## Update

okay got it , you have to use `ngAfterViewInit` method of angualr2 for the same like this

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    document.getElementById('loginInput').value = '123344565';
  }
```

> `ngAfterViewInit` will not throw any error because it will render after template loading

Comment: interesting.  Is this true in angular 6?

Comment: Yes. It is true for Angular 6 as well.

Comment: Is this the preferred way in Angular? It works in Angular 7 as well but I'm not sure if this is the Angular way to do this.

Comment: obviously not @skydev, But as per question requirements I answered this

Answer (score 22):

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('loginInput')).value = '123';
```

Angular cannot take HTML elements directly thereby you need to specify the element type by binding the above generic to it.

**UPDATE::**

This can also be done using ViewChild with #localvariable as shown here, as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38944920/5105411)

```
<textarea  #someVar  id="tasknote"
                  name="tasknote"
                  [(ngModel)]="taskNote"
                  placeholder="{{ notePlaceholder }}"
                  style="background-color: pink"
                  (blur)="updateNote() ; noteEditMode = false " (click)="noteEditMode = false"> {{ todo.note }} 

</textarea>
```

---

```
import {ElementRef,Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
@ViewChild('someVar') el:ElementRef;

constructor(private rd: Renderer2) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.rd); 
      this.el.nativeElement.focus();      //<<<=====same as oldest way
}
```

---

Answer (score 8):

A different approach, i.e: You could just do it 'the Angular way' and use `ngModel` and skip `document.getElementById('loginInput').value = '123';` altogether. Instead:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username"/>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="password"/>
```

and in your component you give these values:

```
username: 'whatever'
password: 'whatever'
```

this will preset the username and password upon navigating to page.

Comment: What if I have to pass the value from the external javascript file to the angular component form field? This is what I did, I have an algorithm sit in the javascript file when the algorithm finished generating the value, and it passes back to the angular form by using this code, getDocumentById('input').value = someValue; . But, when I try to retrieve the value in the event of OnSubmit() I got the undefined value. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Complate Angular Way ( Set/Get value by Id ):

// In Html tag

```
 <button (click) ="setValue()">Set Value</button>
 <input type="text"  #userNameId />
```

// In component .ts File

```
    export class testUserClass {
       @ViewChild('userNameId') userNameId: ElementRef;

      ngAfterViewInit(){
         console.log(this.userNameId.nativeElement.value );
       }

      setValue(){
        this.userNameId.nativeElement.value = "Sample user Name";
      }



   }
```