# How to get a Component's own ElementRef for retrieving BoundingClientRect of this Component?

Tags: angular, typescript, tooltip

I build a tooltip with Angular 5.2.0 and ngrx. When the state updates, the tooltip gets (among other things) an ElementRef to the Element on which it should append (= target). With this target, I can place absolute position the Tooltip:

```
let rect = state.tooltip.target.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
if (rect) {
  this.position.left = rect.left;
  this.position.top = rect.top;
}
```

`state.tooltip.target` is of type [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) which the element opening the Tooltip gets via [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild):

```
@ViewChild('linkWithTooltip') tooltipTarget: ElementRef;

openTooltip() {
    if (this.tooltipOpen) {
      this.tooltipAction.closeTooltip();
    } else {
      this.tooltipAction.openTooltip({
        text: 'foo',
        target: this.tooltipTarget
      });
    }
    this.tooltipOpen = !this.tooltipOpen;
}
```

with the reference in the template:

```
<a #linkWithTooltip href="">Lorem</a>
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944725/how-to-get-dom-element-in-angular-2/38944970) (and in lots of other places).

However, to be able to position the tooltip properly, I have to know the tooltip's size after rendering (for example to center it). What I need is an ElementRef of the Tooltip itself instead of a ViewChild.

**How can I get the dimensions of the current component? Can I retrieve them via the Component's ElementRef? And if yes, how do I get the ElementRef?**

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the dependency injection.

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({ selector: 'tooltip' })
class TooltipComponent {
   constructor(private ref: ElementRef) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can access ref.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect(), but all the values are Zero - I think this is because it is not rendered yet. Is there any way to get around this? I need the height and width of the element, before it is rendered.

Comment: Try accessing the `getBoundingClientRect()` in `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook.

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit` is only called once, the tooltip usually is rendered by user action, so this doesn't work unfortunately... I tried `ngAfterContentChecked` but I get the same result (zero-values). On the other hand, with `ngAfterViewChecked`, I get `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` (which seems logical). I will ask a follow-up question as your answer is definitely right for the question I asked.