# classList.toggle() not working IE11 Angular 7 (Invalid Calling Object)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11

I've just been testing my app on IE11 and I cant figure out why this isn't working,

I have this code it has three elements `.hamburger-small`, `.hamburger-big` and `.menu`

```
<div [class.shown]="!chatbarFullscreen">
        <div [class.disabled]="router.url.includes('home')">
            <img (click)="closeChatbar(true, router.url.includes('home') ? true : false)" *ngIf="chatbarFullscreen" src="../assets/images/whole-app/arrow-right.svg" alt="Arrow Right">
            <img (click)="closeChatbar(false, router.url.includes('home') ? true : false)" *ngIf="!chatbarFullscreen" src="../assets/images/whole-app/arrow-left.svg" alt="Arrow Left">
        </div>
        <img (click)="goHome()" src="../assets/images/chatbar/header-logo.svg" alt="header logo">
        <div id="small" (click)="hamburgerClick()" class="hamburger hamburger--slider hamburger-small">
            <div class="hamburger-box">
              <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="big" (click)="hamburgerClick()" class="hamburger hamburger--slider hamburger-big">
        <div class="hamburger-box">
          <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <p (click)="closeChatbar(false); hamburgerClick();" [routerLink]="['/app/main/home']">Home</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and when you click it, it calls this function

```
hamburgerClick() {
    const small = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.hamburger-small');
    const big = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.hamburger-big');
    const menu = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.menu');
    small.classList.toggle('is-active');
    big.classList.toggle('is-active');
    menu.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

now It works on every other browser, Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Edge but not in IE I've seen similar questions but it seems as if it should work? I'm also getting this error in the console when I click the button for the first time, but it does not happen any other time

[image]

any help would be great..

**EDIT**

I have tried using `@ViewChild()` but it still isn't working, however the Invalid Calling Object error is no longer happening

```
@ViewChild('hamburgerBig') hamburgerBig: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('hamburgerSmall') hamburgerSmall: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('menu') menu: ElementRef;

hamburgerClick() {
    this.hamburgerBig.nativeElement.classList.toggle('is-active');
    this.hamburgerSmall.nativeElement.classList.toggle('is-active');
    this.menu.nativeElement.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried  ViewChild to query the element?

Comment: @Chellappan not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: You can query the element in angular using ViewChild Check this Doc:https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944725/how-to-get-dom-element-in-angular-2

Comment: can you please add HTML with class '.hamburger-small' and '.menu', if this is not defined on page, this is the issue

Comment: @Chellappan using `@ViewChild` did not work

Comment: If it possible can you create stackblitz?

Comment: @BhavinSolanki I have added my full code, but it works on every other browser dont see how If I was missing the elements it would work anywhere else

Comment: you need to place template ref on the element when using ViewChild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `Renderer2` to manipulate dom elements along with `ElementRef` and `ViewChild` as other previously mentioned.

first import `ViewChild, ElementRef` and `Renderer2`

```
import { Renderer2, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

get the Element using `ViewChild` of type `ElementRef` after you've made template references in your DOM, like

```
<div #hamburgerBig></div>
<div #hamburgerSmall></div>
<div #menu></div>

@ViewChild('hamburgerBig') hamburgerBig: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('hamburgerSmall') hamburgerSmall: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('menu') menu: ElementRef;
```

and do your stuff with your hamburgerClick function

```
hamburgerClick() {
    const hamBigIsActive = this.hamburgerBig.nativeElement.classList.contains('is-active');
    const hamSmallIsActive = this.hamburgerSmall.nativeElement.classList.contains('is-active');
    const menuShow = this.menu.nativeElement.classList.contains('show');

    if(hamBigIsActive) {
     this.renderer.removeClass(this.hamburgerBig.nativeElement, 'is-active');
    } else {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.hamburgerBig.nativeElement, 'is-active');
    }
    if(hamSmallIsActive) {
     this.renderer.removeClass(this.hamburgerSmall.nativeElement, 'is-active');
    } else {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.hamburgerSmall.nativeElement, 'is-active');
    }
    if(hamSmallIsActive) {
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.menu.nativeElement, 'show');
    } else {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.menu.nativeElement, 'show');
    }
}
```

or you could just simply use `[ngClass]`(not sure why you aren't using this instead)
 hope this helps

also dont forget to add render to your contructor

```
contructor(private renderer: Renderer2){}
```

Edit: here's the `[ngClass]` implementation

```
<div id="small" 
(click)="hamburgerClick()"
[ngClass] = "{'is-active' : hamClick}"
class="hamburger hamburger-- 
slider hamburger-small">
        <div class="hamburger-box">
          <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
        </div>
</div>
<div id="big" 
(click)="hamburgerClick()"
[ngClass] = "{'is-active' : hamClick}"
class="hamburger hamburger--slider 
 hamburger-big">
    <div class="hamburger-box">
      <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div 
[ngClass] = "{'show' : hamClick}"
class="menu">
    <p (click)="closeChatbar(false); hamburgerClick();" [routerLink]=" 
    ['/app/main/home']">Home</p>
</div>
```

and then just use a function to switch

```
 hamClick: boolean

 hamburgerClick(){
   this.hamClick = !this.hamClick;
 }
```

there you go

Comment: Hey! I used `[ngClass]` and it worked! I didnt even think of that, if you edit your question to include the solution with `[ngClass]` I will mark as correct!

Comment: @SmokeyDawson sure thing, buddy.

Comment: @SmokeyDawson added

Comment: Great! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a test with code below may help you to solve your issue.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public show:boolean = false;
  public buttonName:any = 'Show';

  ngOnInit () {  }

  toggle() {
    this.show = !this.show;

    // CHANGE THE NAME OF THE BUTTON.
    if(this.show)  
      this.buttonName = "Hide";
    else
      this.buttonName = "Show";
  }
}
```

```css
.is-active{color:green;
}
```

```html
<button (click)="toggle()" id="bt">
    Hide
</button>

<ng-container *ngIf="show">
    <div style="margin: 0 auto;text-align: left;">
        <div>
            <label>Name:</label>
            <div><input id="tbname" name="yourname" /></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Email Address:</label>
            <div><input name="email" id="email" /></div></div>
        <div>
            <label>Additional Information (optional):</label>
            <div><textarea rows="5" cols="46"></textarea></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Further, You can try to modify the code based on your requirement.