# how to expand toggle using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to expand toggle class using JavaScript but its not working, i am using setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true') its giving error set-attribute is null.

```
(document.getElementById("collapseid")as HTMLTextAreaElement).setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true')
```

How can we expand the toggle area with div id using JavaScript and without use of click. i am not sure set attribute will solve the issue, i tried to set the attribute true using Edit Html option but it dint work.
unless i click on the toggle button its not expanding, please let me know how to achieve this

Comment: I don't see your html element but did you try `document.getElementById("collapseid").setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true')` ?

Comment: @chg, yes i tried but its giving set attribute null error .. 

Note:HTML is too long to paste it here

Answer (score 0):

`Document.getElementById` will already return you an Element object, no need for that 'as ...' that you're doing.

The function `.setAttribute` is supposed to work in any Element object, so you can fix it by simply doing:

```
let collapseObject = document.getElementById("collapseid")
collapseObject.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true')
```

Now, if you need to add or remove a class, I recommend using the `classList.add()` and `classList.remove()` functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. angular application is not accessing element without use of as html .. i tried to set attribute but its throwing set attribute is null error ..

Comment: Let' see. Is it an AngularJS app, or Angular 2+ app?
You see, using the `document.getElement...` is a bad practice when using Angular, there are better ways

Comment: its angular 6 app.

Comment: Try taking a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944725/how-to-get-dom-element-in-angular-2/39679241 @user2319726